# DynamoDB schema for Instagram

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Hello StackOverflow Community !

I've recently been diving into DynamoDB and exploring its single table design pattern. While I was learning this, I started to wonder how the table schema would look for an application like Instagram, where users can follow others, and can also view, like, and comment on posts from users they follow. For the sake of this discussion, let's exclude the chat feature.

I am trying to figure out a way to get posts from all users that a particular user follows, sorted by timestamp desc. One way I can think of is to use one query to fetch all the users that a user follows, and then use this result set to get all posts from that user and sort it by timestamp desc. Here's the code

```
async function getNewsFeed(userId) {
  try {
    // Step 1: Query User's Followed Users
    const followedUsersResponse = await dynamodb.query({
      TableName: 'SocialAppTable',
      KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :pk AND begins_with(SK, :sk)',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':pk': `USER#${userId}`,
        ':sk': 'FOLLOWER#',
      },
    }).promise();

    // Step 2: Fetch Latest Photos from Followed Users
    const newsFeed = [];
    for (const item of followedUsersResponse.Items) {
      const followedUserId = item.SK.replace('FOLLOWER#', '');

      const photosResponse = await dynamodb.query({
        TableName: 'SocialAppTable',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :pk AND begins_with(SK, :sk)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':pk': `USER#${followedUserId}`,
          ':sk': 'PHOTO#',
        },
        Limit: 5, // Limit to 5 latest photos per followed user
        ScanIndexForward: false, // Sort in descending order by timestamp
      }).promise();

      newsFeed.push(...photosResponse.Items);
    }


    return newsFeed;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching news feed:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

But this seems really inefficient, considering that there might be users following thousands of other users. How do I implement it in a single query / in an optimal way?

Answer (score 0):

You would never fetch all posts of every follower a user follows.

While many social networking apps use graph databases to create a user feed which is interesting to user, you could also implement it naievely using DynamoDB by sampling the content of a user's followers.

You only need to fetch enough items to fill a single page, when the user scrolls to the bottom, fetch the next page of items. This lazy loading will ensure your efficient and you only fetch data as the user needs it.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But even if I had list like the first 25 posts (lets say) sorted by timestamp, I would have to first fetch all the posts from users that a user follows and then sort them by timestamp right? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your sort key should include the timestamp, and you'll get the content back in ordered fashion. Consider using ULIDs for your postIds.

Comment: I was thinking of creating another table for feed service. So when a user posts something, there will be a record for each follower (with the post information) that will be added to this feed table. I will use AWS lambda to insert these records. Each record can have a TTL of 7 days.  I can then use this table to generate user feed like you suggested. Is this a scalable approach? For hot users, I might have to insert millions of records.